# I am trying to install FluentValidation version 6.4.1 nuget in xamarin forms at output gives me like this please sugest me anything

Tags: xamarin, package, nuget

Could not install package 'System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [`Netstandard.Library` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library) first before you add `FluentValidation`.

Take a look at the dependencies section of the [`FluentValidation` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation/) on the NuGet website. It has targets for `.NETStandard 1.0`, `PCL` and `UAP`, but not on `MonoAndroid`.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to accept the answer if it was the solution to your problem.